# Paypal SDK(php) installation difficulties

Tags: php, paypal

I am attempting to install the following API - http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#adaptive-payments

I downloaded the SDK, unziped it, then ran "curl https://raw.github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php/stable-php5.3/samples/install.php | php" as instructed, via shell_exec since I can't install composer(I'm using shared hosting with no ssh access). I also tried system, didn't work. What do you guys think the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

just download the SDK

> If you do not want to use composer, you can grab the SDK zip, unzip the file to your application folder and require the 'vendor/autoload.php' file. This file registers a custom autoloader that can autload the PayPal SDK files.
>   Links
>   Download SDK
>   Source at https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php

and add it to your project, then customise the php file to your need.

they have  [paypal test](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com) so you can create a test account to see if your application is working